# Decompiling a *.DLL to assembly for .net in delphi 4

Tags: .net, delphi, assemblies

I love my Delphi 4 but at the same time I see the need to talk to windows .net
This is a recompiled dll that I found on sourceforge.net/projects/delphinet/ (DelphiNet03.zip) by some nice people that fund the dll from some were.
   The real answer is to make this dll so that fits into Delphi as true Delphi code, and not a dll clip on. So we can make objects that use dot net in Delphi. Because I’m not an assembly freak, I’m freaking out a little with a wee sweek for help!

1/ How do I link the asm code with the data info at the bottom of this code. Can some one show me which calls to look for to make this link to data.
2/ I need to find the beginning of all the procedures and functions, but I cannot find a ‘RET’ statement. And what line is the beginning statement in this code.
3/ How do I identify were the jump statements go to, put them into Delphi format
In this code it looks I can do:-

```
         jle    402890h       \\1000:00402854 7e3a            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402856 0000            
……………………………………………..
         or     ch, [edi+3eh]       \\1000:0040288d 0a6f3e          
                        xrefs first: 1000:00402854 number : 1       \\;                             
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402890 0000
```

//*********************************************************

```
         jle    @@21       \\1000:00402854 7e3a            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402856 0000            
……………………………………………..
         or     ch, [edi+3eh]       \\1000:0040288d 0a6f3e          
                        xrefs first: 1000:00402854 number : 1       \\;
```

@@21 add    [eax], al       \1000:00402890 0000

Is that a correct conversion.
I think a
 xrefs first: 1000:004021d1 number : 1
is the best to follow

4/ I need a good reference on 8086 up assembly code that I can print out and get to learn properly.

I found this asm decomplier of  http://www.cronos.cc/ that is so similar to 
Delphi that it only needs a little more convertion to get it into Delphi asm I think.
It’s only taken me 3 hours to get the file into TMemo and to write a few lines to chop the line over in a stream and reload the memo.

?

```
                      xrefs first: 1000:004041ae number : 1       \\;                             
         dd     4190h       \\1000:00402000 90410000        
         dd     00h       \\1000:00402004 00000000        
         dec    eax       \\1000:00402008 48              
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402009 0000            
         add    [edx], al       \\1000:0040200b 0002            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040200d 0000            
         add    [eax-2bffffd2h], al       \\1000:0040200f 00802e0000d4    
         adc    al, [eax]       \\1000:00402015 1200            
         add    [ecx], al       \\1000:00402017 0001            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402019 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040201b 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040201d 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040201f 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402021 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402023 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402025 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402027 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402029 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040202b 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040202d 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040202f 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402031 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402033 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402035 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402037 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402039 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040203b 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040203d 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040203f 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402041 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402043 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402045 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402047 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402049 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040204b 0000            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040204d 0000            
         add    [ebx], dl       \\1000:0040204f 0013            
         xor    [eax+eax], al       \\1000:00402051 300400          
         or     al, [ecx]       \\1000:00402054 0a01            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402056 0000            
         add    [eax], eax       \\1000:00402058 0100            
         add    [ecx], dl       \\1000:0040205a 0011            
         push   cs       \\1000:0040205c 0e              
         add    al, 50h       \\1000:0040205d 0450            
         mov    gs, [ecx+05h]       \\1000:0040205f 8e6905          
         push   eax       \\1000:00402062 50              
         mov    gs, [ecx+2eh]       \\1000:00402063 8e692e          
         add    eax, f938h       \\1000:00402066 0538f90000      
         add    [ebx], al       \\1000:0040206b 0003            
         jc     402070h       \\1000:0040206d 7201            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040206f 0000            
         jo     40209bh       \\1000:00402071 7028            
         add    al, [eax]       \\1000:00402073 0200            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:00402075 000a            
         sub    eax, 36f0408h       \\1000:00402077 2d08046f03      
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040207c 0000            
         or     ch, [ebx]       \\1000:0040207e 0a2b            
         push   es       \\1000:00402080 06              
         add    al, 6fh       \\1000:00402081 046f            
         add    al, 00h       \\1000:00402083 0400            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:00402085 000a            
         adc    eax, [edi]       \\1000:00402087 1307            
         push   ss       \\1000:00402089 16              
         adc    ecx, [eax]       \\1000:0040208a 1308            
         cmp    cl, cl       \\1000:0040208c 38c9            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040208e 0000            
         add    [ecx], dl       \\1000:00402090 0011            
         pop    es       \\1000:00402092 07              
         adc    [eax], ecx       \\1000:00402093 1108            
         callf  056f:060a9a08h       \\1000:00402095 9a0a066f05      
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040209a 0000            
         or     cl, [ebx]       \\1000:0040209c 0a0b            
         push   es       \\1000:0040209e 06              
         outsd         \\1000:0040209f 6f              
         push   es       \\1000:004020a0 06              
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004020a1 0000            
         or     al, [ebx]       \\1000:004020a3 0a03            
         sub    [edx], al       \\1000:004020a5 2802            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004020a7 0000            
         or     bh, [ecx]       \\1000:004020a9 0a39            
         movsd         \\1000:004020ab a5              
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004020ac 0000            
         add    [edi], al       \\1000:004020ae 0007            
         mov    gs, [ecx+0eh]       \\1000:004020b0 8e690e          
         add    al, 50h       \\1000:004020b3 0450            
         mov    gs, [ecx+40h]       \\1000:004020b5 8e6940          
         cwde          \\1000:004020b8 98              
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004020b9 0000            
         add    [edi], dl       \\1000:004020bb 0017            
         or     al, 16h       \\1000:004020bd 0c16            
         or     eax, 9072b2bh       \\1000:004020bf 0d2b2b0709      
         callf  0000:076f9a09h       \\1000:004020c4 9a6f070000      
         or     ch, [edi+08h]       \\1000:004020c9 0a6f08          
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004020cc 0000            
         or     ch, [eax+ebx]       \\1000:004020ce 0a2c18          
         push   cs       \\1000:004020d1 0e              
         add    al, 50h       \\1000:004020d2 0450            
         or     [edx+d72h], ebx       \\1000:004020d4 099a720d0000    
         jo     402104h       \\1000:004020da 7028            
         or     [eax], eax       \\1000:004020dc 0900            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:004020de 000a            
         add    dl, cs:[esi]       \\1000:004020e0 2e0216          
         or     al, 08h       \\1000:004020e3 0c08            
         sub    eax, 90c2b02h       \\1000:004020e5 2d022b0c09      
         pop    ss       \\1000:004020ea 17              
         pop    eax       \\1000:004020eb 58              
         or     eax, 50040e09h       \\1000:004020ec 0d090e0450      
         mov    gs, [ecx+32h]       \\1000:004020f1 8e6932          
         int    08h       \\1000:004020f4 cd08            
         sub    al, 5ch       \\1000:004020f6 2c5c            
         push   ss       \\1000:004020f8 16              
         adc    eax, [ebx+ebp]       \\1000:004020f9 13042b          
         dec    esi       \\1000:004020fc 4e              
         push   cs       \\1000:004020fd 0e              
         add    al, 50h       \\1000:004020fe 0450            
         adc    [edx+ebx*4], eax       \\1000:00402100 11049a          
         jc     402112h       \\1000:00402103 720d            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402105 0000            
         jo     402131h       \\1000:00402107 7028            
         or     [eax], eax       \\1000:00402109 0900            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:0040210b 000a            
         xor    esi, [esi]       \\1000:0040210d 3336            
         pop    es       \\1000:0040210f 07              
         adc    [edx+ebx*4], eax       \\1000:00402110 11049a          
         outsd         \\1000:00402113 6f              
         pop    es       \\1000:00402114 07              
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402115 0000            
         or     ch, [edi+0ah]       \\1000:00402117 0a6f0a          
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040211a 0000            
         or     dl, [ebx]       \\1000:0040211c 0a13            
         push   es       \\1000:0040211e 06              
         add    eax, 9a041150h       \\1000:0040211f 055011049a      
         sub    [ebx], cl       \\1000:00402124 280b            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402126 0000            
         or     dl, [edx]       \\1000:00402128 0a12            
         push   es       \\1000:0040212a 06              
         adc    al, [c28h]       \\1000:0040212b 1205280c0000    
                        xrefs first: 1000:00402107 number : 1       \\;                             
         or     ch, [edx+eax]       \\1000:00402131 0a2c02          
         sub    ebx, [esi]       \\1000:00402134 2b1e            
         push   cs       \\1000:00402136 0e              
         add    al, 50h       \\1000:00402137 0450            
         adc    [edi+eax], eax       \\1000:00402139 110407          
         adc    [edx+ebx*4], eax       \\1000:0040213c 11049a          
         outsd         \\1000:0040213f 6f              
         pop    es       \\1000:00402140 07              
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402141 0000            
         or     ah, [edx+58170411h]       \\1000:00402143 0aa211041758    
         adc    eax, [ecx+edx]       \\1000:00402149 130411          
         add    al, 0eh       \\1000:0040214c 040e            
         add    al, 50h       \\1000:0040214e 0450            
         mov    gs, [ecx+32h]       \\1000:00402150 8e6932          
         test   eax, 58170811h       \\1000:00402153 a911081758      
         adc    ecx, [eax]       \\1000:00402158 1308            
         adc    [eax], ecx       \\1000:0040215a 1108            
         adc    [edi], eax       \\1000:0040215c 1107            
         mov    gs, [ecx+3fh]       \\1000:0040215e 8e693f          
         sub    al, ffh       \\1000:00402161 2cff            
         db     ff       \\1000:00402163 ff              
         jmp    [edx]       \\1000:00402164 ff2a            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402166 0000            
         adc    esi, [eax]       \\1000:00402168 1330            
         add    eax, 8100h       \\1000:0040216a 0500810000      
         add    [edx], al       \\1000:0040216f 0002            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402171 0000            
         adc    [edx+esi*2], eax       \\1000:00402173 110472          
         xor    eax, [eax]       \\1000:00402176 3300            
         add    [eax+28h], dh       \\1000:00402178 007028          
         add    al, [eax]       \\1000:0040217b 0200            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:0040217d 000a            
         sub    al, 09h       \\1000:0040217f 2c09            
         add    ebp, [eax]       \\1000:00402181 0328            
         or     eax, a0a0000h       \\1000:00402183 0d00000a0a      
         sub    eax, [edi]       \\1000:00402188 2b07            
         add    al, 28h       \\1000:0040218a 0428            
         push   cs       \\1000:0040218c 0e              
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040218d 0000            
         or     cl, [edx]       \\1000:0040218f 0a0a            
         push   es       \\1000:00402191 06              
         add    eax, f6f1717h       \\1000:00402192 0517176f0f      
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402197 0000            
         or     cl, [ebx]       \\1000:00402199 0a0b            
         push   ss       \\1000:0040219b 16              
         lea    eax, [edx]       \\1000:0040219c 8d02            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040219e 0000            
         add    [esi+ecx], ecx       \\1000:004021a0 010c0e          
         add    al, 2ch       \\1000:004021a3 042c            
         push   cs       \\1000:004021a5 260e            
         add    al, 8eh       \\1000:004021a7 048e            
   c160d imul   edi, [eax+28dh], d160c01h       \\1000:004021a9 69b88d020000010c
         sub    edx, [eax]       \\1000:004021b3 2b10            
         or     [ecx], cl       \\1000:004021b5 0809            
         push   cs       \\1000:004021b7 0e              
         add    al, 09h       \\1000:004021b8 0409            
         callf  0000:106f9a09h       \\1000:004021ba 9a6f100000      
         or     ah, [edx+d581709h]       \\1000:004021bf 0aa20917580d    
         or     [esi], ecx       \\1000:004021c5 090e            
         add    al, 8eh       \\1000:004021c7 048e            
         imul   esi, [edx], 17202e9h       \\1000:004021c9 6932e9027201    
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004021cf 0000            
         jo     4021dah       \\1000:004021d1 7007            
         db     0f       \\1000:004021d3 0f              
         add    al, 12h       \\1000:004021d4 0412            
         add    ch, [eax]       \\1000:004021d6 0228            
         add    [eax], eax       \\1000:004021d8 0100            
                        xrefs first: 1000:004021d1 number : 1       \\;                             
         add    [esi], al       \\1000:004021da 0006            
         pop    es       \\1000:004021dc 07              
         or     [edi+11h], ch       \\1000:004021dd 086f11          
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004021e0 0000            
         or     dl, [ebx]       \\1000:004021e2 0a13            
         add    al, 11h       \\1000:004021e4 0411            
         add    al, 0eh       \\1000:004021e6 040e            
         add    al, 6fh       \\1000:004021e8 046f            
         adc    al, [eax]       \\1000:004021ea 1200            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:004021ec 000a            
         adc    eax, [511002bh]       \\1000:004021ee 13052b001105    
         sub    al, [eax]       \\1000:004021f4 2a00            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004021f6 0000            
         adc    esi, [eax]       \\1000:004021f8 1330            
         add    eax, 4e00h       \\1000:004021fa 05004e0000      
         add    [ebx], al       \\1000:004021ff 0003            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402201 0000            
         adc    [ebx], eax       \\1000:00402203 1103            
         outsd         \\1000:00402205 6f              
         adc    [eax], al       \\1000:00402206 1000            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:00402208 000a            
         or     al, [8db8698eh]       \\1000:0040220a 0a058e69b88d    
         add    al, [eax]       \\1000:00402210 0200            
         add    [ecx], al       \\1000:00402212 0001            
         or     edx, [esi]       \\1000:00402214 0b16            
         or     al, 2bh       \\1000:00402216 0c2b            
         db     0f       \\1000:00402218 0f              
         pop    es       \\1000:00402219 07              
         or     [106f9a08h], al       \\1000:0040221a 0805089a6f10    
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402220 0000            
         or     ah, [edx+c581708h]       \\1000:00402222 0aa20817580c    
         or     [eb32698eh], al       \\1000:00402228 08058e6932eb    
         add    al, [esi+eax]       \\1000:0040222e 020406          
         lsl    edx, [edx]       \\1000:00402231 0f0312          
         add    [eax], ebp       \\1000:00402234 0128            
         add    [eax], eax       \\1000:00402236 0100            
         add    [esi], al       \\1000:00402238 0006            
         push   es       \\1000:0040223a 06              
         add    al, 07h       \\1000:0040223b 0407            
         outsd         \\1000:0040223d 6f              
         adc    eax, [eax]       \\1000:0040223e 1300            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:00402240 000a            
         or     eax, 6f050309h       \\1000:00402242 0d0903056f      
         adc    al, 00h       \\1000:00402247 1400            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:00402249 000a            
         adc    eax, [ebx+ebp]       \\1000:0040224b 13042b          
         add    [ecx], dl       \\1000:0040224e 0011            
         add    al, 2ah       \\1000:00402250 042a            
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402252 0000            
         adc    esi, [eax]       \\1000:00402254 1330            
         add    eax, 7600h       \\1000:00402256 0500760000      
         add    [eax+eax], al       \\1000:0040225b 000400          
         add    [ecx], dl       \\1000:0040225e 0011            
         add    al, 72h       \\1000:00402260 0472            
         xor    eax, [eax]       \\1000:00402262 3300            
         add    [eax+28h], dh       \\1000:00402264 007028          
         add    al, [eax]       \\1000:00402267 0200            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:00402269 000a            
         sub    al, 09h       \\1000:0040226b 2c09            
         add    ebp, [eax]       \\1000:0040226d 0328            
         or     eax, a0a0000h       \\1000:0040226f 0d00000a0a      
         sub    eax, [edi]       \\1000:00402274 2b07            
         add    al, 28h       \\1000:00402276 0428            
         push   cs       \\1000:00402278 0e              
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402279 0000            
         or     cl, [edx]       \\1000:0040227b 0a0a            
         push   es       \\1000:0040227d 06              
         add    eax, f6f1717h       \\1000:0040227e 0517176f0f      
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:00402283 0000            
         or     cl, [ebx]       \\1000:00402285 0a0b            
         push   cs       \\1000:00402287 0e              
         add    eax, 8db8698eh       \\1000:00402288 058e69b88d      
         add    al, [eax]       \\1000:0040228d 0200            
         add    [ecx], al       \\1000:0040228f 0001            
         or     al, 16h       \\1000:00402291 0c16            
         or     eax, 908102bh       \\1000:00402293 0d2b100809      
         push   cs       \\1000:00402298 0e              
         add    eax, 106f9a09h       \\1000:00402299 05099a6f10      
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:0040229e 0000            
         or     ah, [edx+d581709h]       \\1000:004022a0 0aa20917580d    
         or     [esi], ecx       \\1000:004022a6 090e            
         add    eax, e932698eh       \\1000:004022a8 058e6932e9      
         add    cl, [esi]       \\1000:004022ad 020e            
         add    al, 07h       \\1000:004022af 0407            
         db     0f       \\1000:004022b1 0f              
         add    eax, 1280212h       \\1000:004022b2 0512022801      
         add    [eax], al       \\1000:004022b7 0000            
         push   es       \\1000:004022b9 06              
         pop    es       \\1000:004022ba 07              
         push   cs       \\1000:004022bb 0e              
         add    al, 08h       \\1000:004022bc 0408            
         outsd         \\1000:004022be 6f              
         adc    eax, [eax]       \\1000:004022bf 1300            
         add    [edx], cl       \\1000:004022c1 000a            
         adc    eax, [ecx+edx]       \\1000:004022c3 130411          
         add    al, 14h       \\1000:004022c6 0414            
         push   cs       \\1000:004022c8 0e              
         add    eax, 146fh       \\1000:004022c9 056f140000      
         or     dl, [ebx]       \\1000:004022ce 0a13            
         add    eax, 511002bh       \\1000:004022d0 052b001105      
         sub    al, [eax]       \\1000:004022d5 2a00            
         add    [ebx], dl       \\1000:004022d7 0013            
         xor    [eax+eax], al       \\1000:004022d9 300400          
         jbe    4022deh       \\1000:004022dc 7600            
                        xrefs first: 1000:004022dc number : 1       \\;                             



         add    fs:[esi+45h], cl       \\1000:004034fc 64004e45        
         push   esp       \\1000:00403500 54              
         dec    ecx       \\1000:00403501 49              
                        xrefs first: 1000:004034b2 number : 1       \\;                             
         outsb         \\1000:00403502 6e              
         jbe    403574h       \\1000:00403503 766f            
         imul   esp, [ebp+43h], 6ch       \\1000:00403505 6b65436c        
         popad         \\1000:00403509 61              
         jnc    40357fh       \\1000:0040350a 7373            
         dec    ebp       \\1000:0040350c 4d              
         jz     403578h       \\1000:0040350d 657468          
         outsd         \\1000:00403510 6f              
         add    fs:[esi+45h], cl       \\1000:00403511 64004e45        
         push   esp       \\1000:00403515 54              
         push   ebx       \\1000:00403516 53              
         jz     40355fh       \\1000:00403517 657445          
         outsb         \\1000:0040351a 6e              
         jnz    40358ah       \\1000:0040351b 756d            
         push   esi       \\1000:0040351d 56              
                        xrefs first: 1000:004034b7 number : 1       \\;                             
         popad         \\1000:0040351e 61              
         insb          \\1000:0040351f 6c              
         jnz    403587h       \\1000:00403520 7565            
         add    [esi+45h], cl       \\1000:00403522 004e45          
         push   esp       \\1000:00403525 54              
         inc    edi       \\1000:00403526 47              
         db     65      ;'e'       \\1000:00403527 65              
                        xrefs first: 1000:004034be number : 1       \\;                             
         db     74      ;'t'       \\1000:00403528 74              
         db     50      ;'p'       \\1000:00403529 50              
         db     72      ;'r'       \\1000:0040352a 72              
         db     6f      ;'o'       \\1000:0040352b 6f              
         db     70      ;'p'       \\1000:0040352c 70              
         db     65      ;'e'       \\1000:0040352d 65              
         db     72      ;'r'       \\1000:0040352e 72              
         db     74      ;'t'       \\1000:0040352f 74              
         db     79      ;'y'       \\1000:00403530 79              
         db     00       \\1000:00403531 00              
         db     4e      ;'n'       \\1000:00403532 4e              
         db     45      ;'e'       \\1000:00403533 45              
         db     54      ;'t'       \\1000:00403534 54              
         db     47      ;'g'       \\1000:00403535 47              
         db     65      ;'e'       \\1000:00403536 65              
         db     74      ;'t'       \\1000:00403537 74              
         db     46      ;'f'       \\1000:00403538 46              
         db     69      ;'i'       \\1000:00403539 69              
         db     65      ;'e'       \\1000:0040353a 65              
         db     6c      ;'l'       \\1000:0040353b 6c              
         db     64      ;'d'       \\1000:0040353c 64              
         db     00       \\1000:0040353d 00
```

could not fit the rest in because of Stack overflow limitions

Comment: Hi Lex, welcome to StackOverflow.  Let me give you a few pointers about the customs in our community, since you're new. A huge dump like that is going to make everyone go "TLDR".  We tend to prefer small, concise questions that make the issue clear.  And since StackOverflow is meant to be a public Q&A repository, posting an email address and asking to have the results sent there goes contrary to the spirit of the site.  One of those two issues is probably why someone voted your question down.

Comment: +1 for Mason because he has taken the time to explain what is "wrong" with the question. 

For the downvoters: leave a comment describing why you downvote something else it doesn't really serve a purpose to downvote...

Comment: Your question is truly the most unanswerable one I have seen with "Delphi" tagged on it, yet.

Answer (score 5):

First, you have decompiled an IL code .NET dll to raw x86 32bit assembly. I mean, the bytes inside the .dll are NOT for a 32bit x86, are for the .NET's VM.

Second, converting that dll it's a totally pointless faraonic task, no one is going to do that. More, let's say you convert the dll, who is going to convert also all the dependencies of that .NET dll? It lacks of sense.

Third, check out the [CrossTalk project](http://www.atozed.com/crosstalk/blog/index.en.aspx). It might help you.

Four, it's time to upgrade your Delphi 4 or to switch to FreePascal, there are a LOT of things very very cool you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You know, Win32 DLLs can be called by managed .NET code.  It's called P/Invoke.  Use it.